# Which database is suitable for serving big timeseries metrics with rollups?

Tags: google-bigquery, aws-aurora

I have big mysql table containing daily metrics for large number of subjects. Here is the hypotetical schema:

```
day DATE
subject_id INT
metric1
metric2
metric3
```

What I want is to find top X subjects (by particular metric) for arbitrary date range. Something like this:

```
SELECT subject_id, SUM(metric1) 
FROM t1 
WHERE day BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-15'
GROUP BY subject_id
ORDER BY SUM(metric1) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Given the fact that the table contains 10M subjects, and the daily metrics for past 365 days, it roughly contains 3.6B rows. No matter how I index/partition it, there are still going to be scenarios which will make the query run for long time (e.g. user selecting past 365 days period). The goal is to have queries complete in few seconds so that they can be used to power dashboards in real-time.

I was trying to make this work with Amazon Aurora (MySql), but havent managed to optimize it to run nearly as fast as it is required.

Seems like the best options are BigQuery and Athena. Still, I was wondering if there are alternatives that are particularly tailored to this specific use case?

> Are values updated, if so how often?

That is a good question. We have many datasets and for vast majority of them, the data is append-only. However, few larger dataset are updated 2-3 times over the course of first 60 days. Only 5% of the data is actually modified, while 95% of data remains the same as on the day of insert.

Comment: Are the values updated?  If so, how often?

Comment: I've updated the question text with the section on how often the data is updated.

Comment: What partitioning schemes have you tried?  `RANGE` on `day` should work. Show proof that it doesn't. Include PLAN.

Comment: I've tried partitioning by RANGE on day. It does help, but it does not solve the problem. User can always specify very big date range that would hit many partitions and still the query times are slow when it needs to go through billion rows. Partitioning by RANGE works for us for other datasets where we have millions of rows, but for this large one it wont do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Athena would be a good choice for this application.  However, queries might not complete in a few seconds.  So, the solution might be to use Athena to generate aggregates and then load the results into a relational database to power your dashboard, AWS Glue can help with this data pipeline.

To generate aggregates in Athena:

You would create an S3 Bucket: `s3://somebucket/`

Then you would create tags formatted as such as your partitions:

`s3://somebucket/date_partition=YYYY-MM-DD/`

> > The goal is to have queries complete in few seconds so that they can be used to power dashboards in real-time.

With this requirement, I would likely pre-calculate aggregates for ranges relevant to data scientists and business users (last trailing year, last trailing month, last trailing year, ect) in Athena and then write them to a relational database.  On AWS, [Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/) is useful for this sort of data pipelining).  If historical data are not updated frequently (or at all), this process can be run as a daily batch process (as @Michael Kutz suggests).

**See:**

[AWS Documentation » Amazon Athena » User Guide » Working with Source Data » Partitioning Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html)

[1.1 Billion Taxi Rides on Amazon Athena](http://tech.marksblogg.com/billion-nyc-taxi-rides-aws-athena.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was leaning towards Amazon Athena since all of our data is already in AWS cloud. There is one problem however. Up till now we were pre-calculating aggregates (in Redshift) for specific months, quarters, years, but we wanted to offer our users to specify ANY date range. This makes pre-calculation impossible and we need to run queries on the fly. I was wondering if there is some sort of specialized database which can handle this type of work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I would still try Athena.  If you use compression on the data (Athena supports GZIP and Snappy among others) and go with a columnar format (Parquet), you might get enough of a reduction in scan size that performance might be acceptable.  

If your users can stomach a 20 second to 30 second delay, then Athena might still do the job.

https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/amazon-athena-w-benchmark-against-redshift-popup-loft-tlv-2017

Comment: Thanks for additional hints. Users cannot really wait 20-30 seconds for the dashboard to appear (and between every page load), so I'm not really sure Athena is suitable for this kind of use case. Do you think that Google's BigQuery is faster?

Comment: I haven't used any BigQuery myself.  However, I have heard very positive things about its performance characteristics.

Comment: BigQuery smashes Redshift when attached to identical dataset... worked on a project a while back surfacing data in Tableau, had to ditch Redshift